# Vue.js access component method or parent method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm new to Vue and managed to make my first app with some glitches but I'm really enjoying it so far. I used a video tutorial which jump started with vue-cli project creation which as turns out is a litte different due to webpack.

I've created the project, the project does mostly what it should right now I'm trying to do some refactoring which includes DRYing out the code.

On each page I would like to access a variable stored in the cookie file I've done the saving and reading on the HomeComponent in the script section which works as promised.

```
<script>
import MenuComponent from '@/components/MenuComponent.vue'
import Typewriter from '@/components/vue-type-writer.vue'

export default {
  name: 'HomeComponent',
  components: {
    MenuComponent,
    Typewriter
  },
  prop:{
      isPlaying: Boolean,
      username: String,
      currentSound: Object
  },
  data() {
      return{
         currentSound: null,
         isPlaying: false,
         username: ''
      }
  },
  methods:{
   clickButton() {
      this.msg= 'test 2'
   },
   toggleSound(){
      var a = this.currentSound;

      if (a.paused) {
        a.play();
        this.isPlaying = true;
      } else {
        a.pause();
        this.isPlaying = false;
      }
   },
   getCookieInfo(){
      var value = "; " + document.cookie;
      var parts = value.split("; weegreename=");
      if (parts.length == 2)
         this.username = parts.pop().split(";").shift();
      else this.username = '';
   },
   seveFormValues (submitEvent) {
      this.username = submitEvent.target.elements.name.value;
      this.$refs.audio1.pause();
      this.$refs.audio2.play();

      var expires = "";
      var days = 31;
      if (days) {
         var date = new Date();
         date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
         expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
      }
      document.cookie = "weegreename=" + (this.username || "")  + expires + "; path=/";

    }
  },
   mounted(){
      this.isPlaying = true;
      this.getCookieInfo();
      if (this.username) this.currentSound = this.$refs.audio2;
      else this.currentSound = this.$refs.audio1;
      this.currentSound.play();
   }
}
</script>
```

Now on every sub page I would like to access the `getCookieInfo()` method to check id the username is set.

I've tried to add this in the main App.vue script section, in the main.js

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  methods: {
    //here the getCookieInfo code from above
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

created a new component whit the methods and then tried to access them in the main app via componentname.method as below.

```
import CookieComponent from '@/components/CookieComponent.vue'

export default {
   // prop:{
   //    isToggled: Boolean
   // },
     components: {
       MenuComponent,
       CookieComponent
     },
   data() {
      return{
         isToggled: false
      }
   },
   methods:{
      clickToggle() {
         this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
      },

   },
   mounted(){
      CookieComponent.getCookieInfo();
   }
}
```

I don't know right now the best approach and I will learn more in the future but this project is time sensitive - I decided to learn vue by making a simple site for my client :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need it on every page it can be put into your App.vue. From there you have three options:

1. Pass the data as a prop to child components.
2. Create an event bus and emit the data to whichever component needs it.
3. Use Vuex to store the data and access it from your components.

If you really want to keep your cookie data inside the component you need to emit it up your component chain.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Depending on how deep your chain goes and how many sibling components you have this can get really messy and in those cases Vuex or an event bus might be a better idea.

Do not try to do things like:

```
CookieComponent.getCookieInfo();
```

Please review the documentation to see good example on how to do component communication.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of stuff, the best practice is to use a **state**. It will save data of your application and will allow you to access them accross all components/pages.

You can see a [simple state management in the Vue doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html), or directly use [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), the official state management library for Vue.

To sum up how it works (with VueX):

- You create a cookieStore:

```
// Where data will be saved
const state = { cookie: {} }

// Getters allow you to access data
const getters = { cookie: state => state.cookie }

// Mutations allow you to modify the state
const mutations = {
  // Set cookie data
  saveCookie (state, cookieData) {
    state.cookie = cookieData
  }
}
```

- In your HomeComponent, you will get the cookie info, and save it in
  the store: `this.$store.commit('saveCookie', cookieData)`
- In all other components, instead of getting the cookie info from the cookie, you can access the saved data from the store and do what you want with it: `this.$store.getters.cookie`